# Отсортировать JSON объект по убыванию

Tags: javascript, json

Имею JSON обьект:

```
 {
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=68203":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Яндекс (Yandex N.V.)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=84098":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        СК ЮЖУРАЛ-АСКО (ACKO)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=67864":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Росгосстрах (РГС, RGSS)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=62700":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Томская распределительная компания (ТРК, TORS)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=64763":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Самараэнерго (SAGO)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=71770":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Сафмар (Европлан, EPLN)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=82762":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Ветка Штирлица\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=62126":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Татнефть (TATN)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=77228":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Попуасс вещает и предсказывает.\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=60522":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Интер РАО ЕЭС (IRAO)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=62207":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Красный октябрь (KROT)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=71341":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Новороссийский комбинат хлебопродуктов (НКХП, NKHP)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=70940":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        Инвестиционный портфель на фондовом рынке - Правила управления\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=62482":{
      "userHere":2,
      "title":"        МРСК Центра (MRKC)\n        \n    "
   },
   "http://forum.mfd.ru/forum/thread/?id=61449":{
      "userHere":1,
      "title":"        М.Видео (MVID)\n        \n    "
   }
}
```

Мне нужно отсортировать его по убыванию, по значению ключа **userHere**.

Comment: В javacript [ключи в объектах неупорядоченны](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/5812238), поэтому в результате сортировки должен получиться массив или `Map`, но никак не обычный объект

Comment: @diraria , Пусть даже так.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, это не JSON. Это литерал объекта JavaScript. JSON представляет собой строковое представление данных, которое просто так сильно напоминает синтаксис JavaScript.

Во-вторых, у вас есть объект. Они несортированы. Порядок элементов не может быть гарантирован. Если вы хотите получить гарантированный заказ, вам нужно использовать массив. Это потребует изменения структуры данных.

Один из вариантов может заключаться в том, чтобы ваши данные выглядели следующим образом:

```
var json = [{
    "title": "title",
    "userHere": 3,
    "url": "url"
}, {
    "title": "title",
    "userHere": 6,
    "url": "url"
}, {
    "title": "title",
    "userHere": 1,
    "url": "url"
}];
```

Теперь у вас есть массив объектов, и мы можем сортировать его.

```
json.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.userHere - b.userHere;
});
```

Получившийся массив будет выглядеть так:

```
var json = [{
    "title": "title",
    "userHere": 1,
    "url": "url"
}, {
    "title": "title",
    "userHere": 3,
    "url": "url"
}, {
    "title": "title",
    "userHere": 6,
    "url": "url"
}];
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684921/sort-json-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Вопрос  полностью  решен.

Comment: @DuckerMan поставьте галочку пожалуйста)